# Running a Ruby process from Rails complains about the Gemfile

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running a ruby process (binary of a gem) from my rails app using system command.

Here is how it looks like:

```
system('someprocess')
```

where someprocess is a ruby bash script. someprocess is part of somegem Gem.

**Question**: Why do I get the following?

> somegem is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)

When the process is running outside my Rails app and doesn't need to know about the Gem. As far as the Rails app is concerned, it's just an outside process, isn't it?

Comment: The problem might be in the gem, what gem is it? And what does it say when you do `which somegem` from your Rails root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try telling Bundler to use a clean env:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  system 'someprocess'
end
```